# ng-options for interpolated label and value

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

I have an array

```
terms = [5,10,15,20,25]
```

and I'm trying to use `ng-options` in a `select` statement

```
<select ng-model="myNumbers" ng-options="term + ' years' as term for term in terms">
```

which produces

```
<option value="?"></option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="15">15</option>
<option value="20">20</option>
<option value="25">25</option>
```

What I want it to produce is

```
<option value="5">5 years</option>
<option value="10">10 years</option>
<option value="15">15 years</option>
<option value="20">20 years</option>
<option value="25">25 years</option>
```

Basically trying to solve 3 problems.

1. Set the `label` correctly (`5 years`, etc)
2. Set the `value` correctly (`value="5"`, etc)
3. Remove the initial blank option (start at 5)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple adjustment to move the string to the `as` portion

```
<select  ng-options="term  as term + ' years' for term in terms"></select>
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/1HMWl1hVRz3wBmhDIJYu)**</kbd>

Comment: nice.  now how to set the `value` correctly and remove the initial blank option?

Comment: you already have the value in the `ng-model` variable. Refresh my demo and select something

Comment: if you set one option inside <select> can make it display what you want

Comment: use `ng-init` for initialising the `ng-model`. Then the initial blank entry will be gone. `<select ng-init="myNumbers=terms[0]" ng-options="term  as term + ' years' for term in terms"></select>`

Comment: yes, I know. I suggested it for an easy fix. It should be done from controller.